# What is making Chrome's Utility Speech Recognition Service consuming too much memory?

Tags: google-chrome, memory, chromium, memory-management, memory-leaks

I recently started to find Chrome (actually Chromium) consuming too much memory, so, I opened the browser's Task manager to observe which pages/processes are doing that the most, and I always found the process: `Utility: Speech recognition service` is consuming big memory footprint and it keeps growing, even I'm neither opening any tabs that's using the speech recognition nor activating any browser extensions that are using it as well!

[image: Screenshot: Task manager: Utility: Speech recognition service]

I tried to kill it many times before (End process), but, it keeps running again!

**Why this is happening, and how can I minimize it?**

---

OS: `Linux Ubuntu 18.04`

Chromium Version: `97.0.4692.71 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit)`

Answer (score 2):

## BLUF

turn off live captions

## Storytime

I've got a similar problem, with the `Speech Recognition Service` consuming too much CPU on my poor old intel dual-core.

I could solve this by turning off live captions, which seems to have disabled the `Speech Recognition Service` altogether, so I'd expect it to also solve any memory issues with the service.

## Steps

- Go to captions settings page

  - `Settings` > `Accessibility` > `Captions`
  - *or* enter into URL bar `chrome://settings/captions`
- Turn off `Live Caption`

## References

https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/66203/racing-my-cpu-utility-speech-recognition-service

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).